# iOS javascript POST request weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, post, safari

I am making a GUI where it is necessary for the server to know exactly what state the UI is in. Hence, I am sending a POST request in every `onclick` and on every `change`. My UI is behaving correctly on Chrome in Linux and on Windows - that is that it is sending just a bunch of POSTs to my flask server, which processes the data and returns a blank response `return ('', 204)`. And the UI still stays on the same page, hence the ui is still visible. But safari on ios is behaving differently, when I do anything that triggers the POST update, it sends the post and then tries to move the browser location to the `192.168.1.1/query?arg=value` of the POST URL and it tries to render the blank response leaving me at a white page. Why is this happening?

```
function post(path) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", path)
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

And the javascript (the `type=text` is a jQuery rotary dial called *jQuery Knob*)

```
<input type="text" class="dial" value="0" id="myRange"><br /><br />
<button id="myButton" onclick="(function() { post('/query?arg1=1234'); })();">PUSH ME</button>
<script>
    $(".dial").knob({
        'min':0,
        'max':100,
        'fgColor':"#66CC66",
        'angleOffset':-125,
        'angleArc':250,
        'rotation':"clockwise",
        'change': function(v) { post('/slider?value='+Math.round(v)); }
    });
</script>
```

Ideally I want the iOS browser to behave the same way chrome on desktop does. Thanks for your comments and help in general.

Comment: IMO the IOS behavior is “standard” and Chrome is doing something strange.  If you submit a form whether by javascript or plain html, the browser should load the new page.  If you want to remain on the same page, use ajax to send your data to the server.

Comment: Interesting point actually. Didn't think of it that way. My backup option was websocket (cause I'm developing an app that is meant to be run in the local network so we can safely assume no NAT or a firewall on the way). But ajax sounds way more interesting. I'll try that then. Thanks mate

Comment: Yeah, jQuery.post() - which is ajax I believe, solved it. Thanks for the tip mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Ajax `jQuery.post()` and that solved it.